# Change color of List View row to user's desired color

Tags: android, listview

I'm developing a "Notes" application. I've added an option in Action Bar which shows different colors. When users click on any color it changes the background color but as soon as the user exits that particular activity and goes back to the List View the color is lost. It doesn't show on that particular list view item. Can anyone tell me how can i retain the color changed state? Thank you.

Comment: `SharedPreferences`

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest thing to do would be to save the user's color choice in `SharedPreferences`. You could read the list's background color in `onCreate()` and update the preference every time the user chose a color from the toolbar.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("PREFS_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int color = prefs.getInt("KEY_COLOR", -1);

    if (color == -1) {
        color = /* your default color here */;
    }

    listView.setBackgroundColor(color);
}

private void onToolbarColorSelected(int color) {
    listView.setBackgroundColor(color);

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("PREFS_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    prefs.edit().putInt("KEY_COLOR", color).apply();
}
```

Comment: If I want to change the color of only one list view item suppose i want to change the color of the row which has position[2] then this method will work?

Comment: The general idea would work. Instead of calling `setBackgroundColor()` in `onCreate()` you'd call it in your adapter's `getView()` method (and check if `position == 2`)

Comment: Thank you. I understood. But in getView() method when the position == 2 then how will i change the color of position = 2 ? Do I have to only call listView.setBackgroundColor() or is there any other way?

Comment: The view you return from `getView()` is the view being displayed in that position. Under the normal pattern where you return `convertView` from this method, you would call `convertView.setBackgroundColor(position == 2 ? posTwoColor : otherColor)`